# if statement syntax - different than taught

Tags: python

I've been seeing code like this on the internet and in response to my questions in people's if statements.

```
if (not (letter.lower() in word) or not(letter.lower() in guessed_letters)) and letter != ' ':
```

Could someone break that down? This is in the context of a raw input being compared to a phrase not given.

Comment: Which part specifically do you have a question about?

Comment: "Different than taught" only has meaning if you tell us what you were taught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the top:

```
(not (letter.lower() in word) or not(letter.lower() in guessed_letters)) and letter != ' '
```

This is two terms separated by `and`:

```
a = (not (letter.lower() in word) or not(letter.lower() in guessed_letters))
b = letter != ' '
result = a and b
```

The meaning of that `b` is pretty obvious, so let's give it a better name:

```
a = (not (letter.lower() in word) or not(letter.lower() in guessed_letters))
not_space = letter != ' '
result = a and not_space
```

But you're still mystified by that `a`, so let's break it down the same way. It's a parenthesized expression, which is the same as what's inside the parens, so let's skip that part and go right to:

```
x = not (letter.lower() in word)
y = not (letter.lower() in guessed_letters)
a = x or y
```

These should now be small enough to parse in your head. If not, you can go one step further—but note that you can also just add some `print` calls, like `print(letter, x, y)` and run the program and see if that helps.

Anyway, let's give them names:

```
not_found = not (letter.lower() in word)
not_guessed = not (letter.lower() in guessed_letters)
new_letter = not_found or not_guessed
not_space = letter != ' '
result = new_letter and not_space
```

And now you're done: you're checking that the letter is a new letter (neither in the word, nor guessed), and not a space.

---

If you wanted to take this to the limit, it would look something like this:*

```
a1a1a1a = letter.lower
a1a1a1 = a1a1a1a()
a1a1a = a1a1a1 in word
a1a1 = (a1a1a)
a1a = not a1a1
a1b1a1a = letter.lower
a1b1a1 = a1b1a1a()
a1b1a = a1b1a1 in guessedletters
a1b1 = (a1b1a)
a1b = not a1b1
a1 = a1a or a1b
a = (a1)
b = letter != ' '
result = a and b
```

And then you can go step by step, eliminating the ones that do nothing, giving intermediate names to the meaningful ones from the lowest level up, and so on.

But in real life, you'd never go that far unless you were trying to interpret code by hand to understand the language definition or something.

<sub>* In fact, if you really want to break it down exactly the way Python does, you can ask Python to do it for you, by using the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
if letter.lower() not in word or letter.lower() not in guessed_letters and letter != ' ':
```

why unnwanted brackets, if can handle the statment

Comment: I agree that this is more pythonic ... but Im not sure it answwers his question (to be honest Im not entirely sure what the question is) +1 none the less

Comment: i am also not sure, just formated it in pythonic way

Comment: I disagree that it's Pythonic. "Explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: Taking out the brackets changes the meaning. `A or B and C` is not the same as `(A or B) and C`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - seems explicit to me, but I'd favor `letter.lower() not in word + guessed_letters + [' ']`, or init guessed_letters to [' '] and do .`letter.lower() not in word + guessed_letters`.

Comment: @tdelaney, *shrug*. Requiring the reader to know a given language's choices on precedence order is something I tend to try to avoid. Then again, I work with a polyglot team, so any code I write -- in any language -- will be read if not modified by at least a few people who do 80% of their work in something different.

Comment: "Explicit is better than Implicit" Zen of python, whether one should use an explicit or implicit method depends upon the problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

if either the lowercase letter is not in the word or the lowercase letter is not in the list of guessed numbers, and the letter is not a space, then do something ... it is likely for a hangman type game

usually the something you do is add it to the list of guessed letters (at a minimum)